# How to dynamically load table from one db to other db and append few characters in table names in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I append 2 letters like de_ tables and copy that tables from one database to other database in snowflake with the table structure and data also

Comment: You would probably want to clone the whole database and alter the tables to change their names. You can do that in bulk with a SQL generator or stored procedure.

Comment: I wanted to create dynamically table names using stored procedure and table structure and data load along with that

Comment: Sounds like you know how to do this already.  Are you looking for somebody to code the SP for you?  @GregPavlik is right about using cloning for this.  Your SP should just iterate through the list of tables in a database and clone each one with a new name to the other DB.  Faster, cheaper, cleaner.